# Comparing event $X$ and $Y$, if $P(X) = o(1)$ and $P(Y) = \Omega(1)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, asymptotics

Consider two probabilistic events $X$ and $Y$:

if $P(X) = o(1)$ and $P(Y) = \Omega(1)$ (where $o(.)$ and $\Omega(.)$ are [little Oh-notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations)), is it possible to compare the two event $X$ and $Y$? (for example to say, event $Y$ is much likelier than event $X$)

Comment: $P(Y) = \omega(1)$ is equivalent to $P(Y) \to \infty$ which is impossible.

Comment: Oops. Big Omega.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for. The conditions are equivalent to "$P(X) \to 0$," and "for some $c>0$ we eventually have $P(Y) \ge c$." So eventually $P(X)$ will be smaller than $P(Y)$.